# Laravel + Passport api get records by Auth

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent, laravel-passport

Problem is i want to take records by Auth::user()->department How to solve this problem in Laravel api + Passport.

> "message": "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\API\Auth' not found",

**Controller/Api/ApiController.php**

```
public function index(){
$banks = Bank::where('bank', Auth::user()->department)->orderby("created_at",'desc')->get();
   return $this->sendResponse($banks->toArray(), 'Амжилттай уншигдлаа.');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That's it, You just need to add Auth Class in your php file.

```
use \Auth;
```